# Unique Lifting Property - Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, covering-spaces

I am currently studying Hatcher's book on Algebraic Topology.

I would like to understand the proof of Proposition 1.34 on page 62, concerning the uniqueness of a lift of a map $f: Y\to X$, given a covering space $p:\tilde X\to X$. The Author is trying to show that some set is at the same time open and closed (and since $Y$ is connected this implies that this set is the whole Y), but I cannot follow his reasoning.

I understand the setting of the proof, but the following is not clear to me: let $\tilde U_1$ and $\tilde U_2$ be the sheets containing $\tilde f_1(y)$ and $\tilde f_2(y)$ respectively, then

> If $\tilde f_1(y)\neq \tilde f_2(y)$  then $\tilde U_1\neq \tilde U_2$, hence $\tilde U_1$ and $\tilde U_2$ are disjoint and $f_1\neq f_2$ throughout the neighborhood $N$. On the other hand, if $\tilde f_1(y)=\tilde f_2(y)$ then $\tilde U_1=\tilde U_2$ so $\tilde f_1 = \tilde f_2$ on $N$ since $p \tilde f_1 = p \tilde f_2$ and $p$ is injective on $\tilde U_1=\tilde U_2$. Thus the set of points where $\tilde f_1$ and $\tilde f_2$ agree is both open and closed in Y.

- Where is the Author using that the two maps agree at a point?
- Why $\tilde f_1(y)\neq \tilde f_2(y)\implies \tilde U_1\neq \tilde U_2$ and $\tilde f_1(y)=\tilde f_2(y)\implies \tilde U_1=\tilde U_2$?

I am aware of the fact that other questions on this particular proof have been asked, but they are still obscure to me.

Comment: Hatcher is arguing as follows: The set where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are *not* equal is open, but so is the set where they *are*. This means that the set where they are is both closed and open (in that order). The basic idea is that a set is clopen if and only if its complement as well as the set itself are open.

Comment: In which point of the proof is he understanding what you argue? Could you be more detailed please?
I am really struggling to understand the proof in general, so a more detailed explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: I have added some of my doubts in the question

Comment: The author uses that the two maps agree at one point to say that the set of points where they agree is clopen and nonempty (the empty set is always clopen !). You shoud add the definition of $\tilde U_1, \tilde{U_2}$

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying my first doubt. I have added a definition of the two sets $\tilde U_1, \ \tilde U_2$. I still need to understand my second point and how is he proving that the set of points where the two functions agree is open/closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the proof Hatcher shows that the set $A$ of points of $Y$ where $\tilde f_1$ and $\tilde f_2$ agree is is both open and closed in $Y$. Thus, if $Y$ is connected, then either $A = \emptyset$ or $A = Y$. This is true without any assumption on the lifts.

This implies (but Hatcher does not explicitly mention it) that if the lifts agree at one point of $Y$, then $A = Y$.

Concerning your second question: $p^{-1}(U)$ is the *disjoint union* of open sets $U_\alpha$ each mapped homeomorphically to $U$ by $p$. Let $p_\alpha : U_\alpha \to U$ denote the homeomorphism obtained by restricting $p$. We have $\tilde f_i(y) \in  U_{\alpha_i} = U_i$. Thus, if $U_1 = U_2$, i.e. $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$, then $\tilde f_1(y) = p^{-1}_{\alpha_1}(y) = p^{-1}_{\alpha_2}(y) = \tilde f_2(y)$. Conversely, if $U_1 \ne U_2$, then trivially $\tilde f_1(y) \ne \tilde f_2(y)$ because the $U_\alpha$ are pairwise disjoint. Thus $U_1 = U_2$ if and only if $\tilde f_1(y) = \tilde f_2(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\varphi,\psi:Y\to \tilde X$ are continuous lifts of $f$ which agree at some point of $Y$. Let $S=\{y\in Y:\varphi(y)=\psi(y)\}$. The set $S$ is non-empty.

Suppose $y_0\in S$. Let $\varphi(y_0)=\psi(y_0)=\tilde x_0$ and $p(\tilde x_0)=x_0$. Let $U$ be an evenly covered open set containing $x_0$ and $\tilde U$ be an open subset of $\tilde X$ containing $\tilde x_0$ such that the restriction of $p$ gives a homeomorphism from $\tilde U$ to $U$. As both $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are continuous and the image of $y_0$ under $\varphi$ and $\psi$ is in $\tilde U$, there is an open set $V$ containing $y_0$ such that $\varphi(V)\subseteq \tilde U$ and $\psi(V)\subseteq \tilde U$. Let $y\in V$. As $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are lifts of $f$, we see that $p(\varphi(y))=f(y)=p(\psi(y))$. As $\varphi(y),\psi(y)\in \tilde U$ and the restriction of $p$ to $\tilde U$ is injective, we see that $\varphi(y)=\psi(y)$. So we have found an open set $V$ containing $y_0$ such that $V\subseteq S$. Hence, it follows that $S$ is open.

Suppose $y_0\notin S$. Let $f(y_0)=x_0$, $\varphi(y_0)=\tilde x_1$ and $\psi(y_0)=\tilde x_2$. As $p\circ\varphi=f=p\circ\psi$, it follows that $p(\tilde x_1)=p(\tilde x_2)=x_0$. Let $U$ be an evenly covered open set containing $x_0$. As $\tilde x_1\neq \tilde x_2$, there exist disjoint open sets $\tilde U_1$ and $\tilde U_2$ in $\tilde X$ such that $\tilde x_1\in \tilde U_1$, $\tilde x_2\in \tilde U_2$ and the restrictions of $p$ give homeomorphisms $\tilde U_1\to U$ and $\tilde U_2\to U$. As $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are continuous and the images of $y_0$ under $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are in $\tilde U_1$ and $\tilde U_2$, we can find an open set $V$ containing $y_0$ such that $\varphi(V)\subseteq \tilde U_1$ and $\psi(V)\subseteq \tilde U_2$. As $\tilde U_1$ and $\tilde U_2$ are disjoint, for each $y\in V$ we see that $\varphi(y)\neq \psi(y)$. So we have found an open set $V$ containing $y_0$ such that $V\cap S=\emptyset$. Hence, it follows that $S$ is closed.

Thus, as $Y$ is connected we see that $S=Y$ and so it follows that $\varphi=\psi$.