# $p:\tilde{X}\to X$ a covering map, $\tilde{X}$ path connected, show a deck transformation $\tau$ fixes a point in $\tilde{X}$ iff $\tau=id_\tilde{X}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

The backwards direction is clear, and for the forwards direction I think I need to use the homotopy lifting property for paths since $\tilde{X}$ is path connected. So I start with for some $x_0\in\tilde{X}$, $\tau(x_0)=x_0$. Now I think I need to use $x_0$ as a base for a path $\gamma$ and somehow show that $\tau(\gamma)=\gamma$. Not really sure if this is right or how to proceed if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p : \tilde X \to X$ be any covering map and $f : Y \to X$ be any map. It is a well-known theorem in the theory of covering maps that for any two lifts $\tilde {f_1}, \tilde {f_2}: Y \to \tilde X$ of $f$ the set of points of $Y$ where $\tilde {f_1}$ and $\tilde {f_2}$ agree is open and closed in $Y$. See for example Hatcher's book on Algebraic Topology. Also see [Unique Lifting Property - Algebraic Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3496722).

Thus, if $Y$ is connected, then $\tilde {f_1} = \tilde {f_2}$ if and only if $\tilde {f_1}(y_0) = \tilde {f_2}(y_0)$ for a single $y_0 \in Y$.

Therefore in your question it suffices to assume that $\tilde X$ is connected. Now simply observe that any deck transformation $\tau$ is a lift of $p$.